# Analytic continuation of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-x E_n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, summation, analytic-continuation

Suppose we define a function $f(x)$ by the following sum:
$$f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-x E_n}$$
where $E_n$ is a sequence which is at most $O(n)$. It is known $f(x)$ does not form a natural boundry on the imaginary $x$ axis. Does there, in general, exist a closed form expression for the analytic continutation of $f(x)$ to $f(-x)$?

Comment: You don't even have a closed form expression for $f(x)$ itself, so why would you expect one for the analytic continuation?

Comment: What is "the imaginary $x$ axis"?

Comment: $f$ has a natural boundary on $f(i x)$ for all x.